# Why would VB6 compiled application require VB5 VM?

Tags: dll, vb6, vb5

I have upgraded a `VB5` product to `VB6` and produced an executable from the `VB6` IDE.  It will not execute properly without the presence of `MSVBVM50.DLL`.  Without it it generates the following error:

```
Automation error - cannot find specified module.
```

What could the reason for this?

Is it possible that there is a component `DLL` that has been compiled in `VB5` that would require the `VB5` VM?

Answer (score 4):

In the VB6 IDE the Project > Components menu will show the Components dialog and Project > References will show the References dialog.

Find which components are ticked and make sure that they are the VB6 versions and not VB5 versions. Many of the standard controls were updated with VB6.

In particular look for the various 'Microsoft windows Common Controls' entries as they are some of the ones you are least likely to notice changing as they are visually identical in the toolbox.

Comment: Would there be any harm in including the VB5 runtime in the short term?

Comment: Note that for long-term considerations you should try to swap out the VB5 to VB6 components. The latest (which is still pretty old in most cases) VB6 components will tend to operate better & have fewer incompatibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion is correct.  If you are using a component (DLL, OCX) that depends on the VB5 runtime you can't run your program without it.

You need to check your referenced DLL's and components to search for the one using VB5 VM.